# Edit 2 controller from one controller (Correct)

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3, cakephp-model

i have small problem so i need some help. maybe its very easy but i just need a push...  so i am withing one controller

```
public function edit($id = null) {
    if (!$this->TypologyPicture->exists($id)) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid typology picture'));
    }
    if ($this->request->is(array('post', 'put'))) {
            if(empty($this->data['TypologyPicture']['pic_path']['name'])){
                unset($this->request->data['TypologyPicture']['pic_path']);
              }
        if ($this->TypologyPicture->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The typology picture has been saved.'));
            return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The typology picture could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    } else {
        $options = array('conditions' => array('TypologyPicture.' . $this->TypologyPicture->primaryKey => $id));
        $this->request->data = $this->TypologyPicture->find('first', $options);

        //$options1 = array('conditions' => array('Typology.id' => $id));
        $opt =  array('conditions' => array('Typology.id' => $this->request->data['TypologyPicture']['typology_id']));
        $this->request->data = $this->Typology->find('first', $opt);

    }


    if ( AuthComponent::user('role')==='admin' ||AuthComponent::user('role')==='superadmin' ){ //if the user is admin or superadmin, show all on dropdown
            $items = $this->Typology->TypologyItem->find('list');
        } else {// else if the user is author, show only item created by him.
            $items = $this->Typology->TypologyItem->find('list', array('conditions' => array('TypologyItem.user_id' => AuthComponent::user('id'))));            
        }
    $typologyCategories = $this->Typology->TypologyCategory->find('list');
    $typologyConditions = $this->Typology->TypologyCondition->find('list');
    $users = $this->Typology->TypologyUser->find('list');
    $this->set(compact('items', 'typologyCategories', 'typologyConditions', 'users'));

    if ( AuthComponent::user('role')==='admin' ||AuthComponent::user('role')==='superadmin' ){
        $typologies = $this->TypologyPicture->ItemTypologyPicture->find('list');
    } else {
        $typologies = $this->TypologyPicture->ItemTypologyPicture->find('list', array('conditions' => array('ItemTypologyPicture.user_id' => AuthComponent::user('id'))));
        }
    $this->set(compact('typologies'));
}
```

so as you see from contact controller i want to access the contact that i want to edit and its its pictures that are stored in **contact_picture** table. contact by itself has like an icon or an avatar,  and in contact picture are stored the gallery. so  here the problem is that i get all the data as it supposed to, but the image of the contact (avatar, or icon) doesent dispay, the path is retrived correctly but it just doesent display the image.

So what im asking is that if there is another way or easy way or even better way to do that i would really appruciate it...really.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**  The View Part:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('TypologyPicture', array('type'=>'file')); ?>
        <legend><?php echo __('Edit Typology Picture'); ?></legend>
    <?php
    $dir = "/img/uploads/typology/images/"; 
        echo $this->Form->input('id'); ?>

<?php echo $this->Form->input('Typology.item_id',array('empty'=>true)); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('Typology.title'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('Typology.description');?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('Typology.thumbnail',array('type'=>'file')); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('Typology.typology_category_id',array('empty'=>true)); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('Typology.typology_condition_id',array('empty'=>true)); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('Typology.price',array('placeholder'=>'Price')); ?>
<!-- Here is the second part of the update -->
<?php echo $this->Form->input('pic_path', array('label'=>'Picture','type'=>'file'));
        echo $this->Form->input('hiddenimage', array('type'=>'hidden','value'=> $this->Form->value('pic_path') )); 
        $Image = $this->Form->value( 'pic_path');       
            if(empty($Image) || $Image==NULL)
                    {$Image = "/img/uploads/noimg.jpg";}
                else {$Image = $dir . $Image;   }
        echo $this->Html->image($Image,array('align'=>'absbottom','style'=>'max-height:100px'));
    ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit')); ?>
```

So when i do echo to the image it doesent display correctly... if i remove the typology model part like a normal edit, it displays normal...

Comment: If the path is being retrieved correctly, I would have thought it's more likely to be a view problem - can you post your view code? Have you checked that you can navigate to the image using the path that is returned?

In terms of the way you are retrieving your data, I think we need to know more about your models ie. Why are you finding using Contact.id in a $this->Typology->find...I would have though it would be more like: Typology.contact_id if Contact hasMany Typology?

Comment: @theotherdy here is the correct code... what do you think? i might be mistaking???

Comment: Thanks @landi, and the relationship between Typology and TypologyPicture? Not sure I completely understand - can you navigate to the path in $Image

Comment: @theotherdy The relation is TypologyPicture Belongs to Typology, and Typology hasMany TypoogyPictures.  and as for $image, yes if i remove the code that i added, or if i put 

$opt =  array('conditions' => array('Typology.id' => $this->request->data['TypologyPicture']['typology_id']));
        $this->request->data['Typology'] = $this->Typology->find('first', $opt); 

The image displays but then the related datta goes missing..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try by removing the img part from $dir and $Image;

```
$dir = "/img/uploads/typology/images/";
```

should be

```
$dir = "uploads/typology/images/";
```

and

```
{$Image = "/img/uploads/noimg.jpg";}
```

should be

```
{$Image = "uploads/noimg.jpg";}
```